# scriptaculous effect.toggle to left and right instead

Tags: prototypejs, scriptaculous

Can anyone tell me how to use `Effect.toggle()` to toggle to left and right instead of up and down? Or is there any other effect in Scriptaculous that does this ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `toggle()` method only supports 3 effects appear, slide, and blind - if you want to do left to right I would suggest using the `morph()` method as you can put any styles in there and they will be changed back and forth

for example

```
// close the div horizontally
$('firstdiv').morph('width:0px;');

//open the div horizontally
$('firstdiv').morph('width:auto;');
```

Comment: Thanks but not what i was looking for :( Guess there really is no other way.